# Calling from Android app itself

Tags: android, phone-call

I searched and I found the following code for calling using android.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

It just results the usable or default phone apps installed to do the call, when terminates, returns to base app. But I need to develop a app that can call from the app itself (not allowing other apps or built-in system), and will show the call status and store responses and other records(like talking and inputing data simalteniously). 
How can I do that(just calling part) or what resource are there for doing so?

Comment: Unless you are implementing your own VOIP, what you want is not possible at the SDK application level, to the best of my knowledge. You are welcome to create your own ROM mod where you replace the stock Android call handling with something else, though.

Comment: Well, then putting the phone app as a part of my app at a side and other side for data input...is that possible? I specially need  data input provision during call (or the technologies Used in Samsung Tab 2 10.1 or Galaxy Note N8000)

Comment: I have no idea what "data input provision" means. You do not have access to the baseband radios or much of the low-level telephony system plumbing from an ordinary SDK application.

Comment: I meant another part where there will be some text field to write the responses in the screen beside the call program. Anyway, thanks for quick response. :(

Comment: Is it possible to send the call app to run in background and base app to be focused from the starting of call? I mean, you click the call button on home app, but you can still see the base app but the call app started and shown in top notification bar. I experienced such while using android, calling someone, then pressing home button or using task manager to to switch program. Is there any way to do that using code in base app?